# Citrix ICA Client opens when I open e-mail; how do I get it to stop?

Tags: citrix

Mac environment, Safari, e-mail through AT&T/Yahoo.  When I open an e-mail, Citrix ICA Client kicks in; tries to download "categoryhtml-aspx" and then a failure notice comes up.  I have used Citrix ICA Client without incident for years to connect to work server, but I only use it then and it has never flared up like this.  Also, the Citrix ICA icon appears in my dock and I cannot get rid of it.  I have never had this "connection" between Citrix and anything else.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the Citrix client you have installed has associated itself with the .ASPX file type. If you can manually download the file that the ICA client is trying to open (i.e. right click on the link in your browser and save the file to your desktop), you can then right click on the file on your desktop and go to 'Get Info' and change the file type association in there.

If that doesn't work, you could try renaming/removing the Launch Manager cache. You can find it in ~/Library/Preferences/ and it'll be named exactly like "com.apple.LaunchServices.plist" or something similar to that depending on your version of OS X. Once you're renamed/removed it, restart and test.

Alternatively if *that* doesn't work, you could download RCDefaultApp from http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/ - this is a preference pane add-in that basically shows you what all of your current file associations are, and you can manage it from there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that whoever controls your Citrix environment has enabled content redirection, causing your Citrix PNagent to associate itself with one of Outlook's file types.